# Bootstrap datepicker is not working and not any error occur also

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I want to integrate bootstrap date picker in my web application using php.the problem is that no any error show and not working plz help me.

```
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/css/datepicker.min.css" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/css/datepicker3.min.css" />
     <script src="<?php echo SITE_JS?>jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
     <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Date</label>
            <div class="col-xs-5 date">
                <div class="input-group input-append date" id="dateRangePicker">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="date" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon add-on"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#dateRangePicker')
            .datepicker({
                format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
                startDate: '01/01/2010',
                endDate: '12/30/2020'
            })
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Check your console once.

Comment: If there's nothing in the console, try making a jsfiddle so we can actually try it.

Comment: i have checked console but there are not display any error

Comment: Have you included jquery ?

Comment: yes i have included jquery

Comment: I think you did not included the jquery library. i have checked it in jsfiddle.net and it is working fine for me.

Comment: i have included jquery mehar

Comment: jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
try to change with this line jQuery noConflict

Comment: tried but not working Er M Channa

Comment: where have you included jquery, at the top or at the end of script?

Comment: i dont see your core bootstrap css and JS file.

Comment: i have included jquery at top of the script

Comment: Here is the working example of your code http://jsfiddle.net/mehar/5xjorzdg/

Comment: Thanks mehar for your effort but this code is not working in my application and not show any error

Comment: @user2576085 Try disabling all other javascript to see if there is something conflicting with your scripts.

Comment: i have disabled all other javascript but still not working

Comment: @HiralPatel Please provide an example that doesn't work. Either create a jsfiddle (preferred) or provide the link to your website. It doesn't seem like anyone else is able to reproduce your error.

Comment: thanks mike, but i can't show you my website bcz of i have not permit to show web site to other person as per my company policy..

Answer (score 0):

change to this code its work prefectly in jsfiddle

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('#dateRangePicker')
    .datepicker({
        format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
        startDate: '01/01/2010',
        endDate: '12/30/2020'
    })
  });
```

Comment: ok then try to change the $('#date') its your id in jqeury and also give this id to your input field  like <input type="text" id= "date" class="form-control" name="date" />

Comment: thanks, i have given id to input like "date" but still not working.

Comment: try this one $('#dateRangePicker input').datepicker({
});

Comment: SITE_JS is constant for js folder path

Comment: r u sure ur library included successfully ?